# Spectra of a weighted path graph

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory

In [Spectra of Simple Graphs](https://www.whitman.edu/documents/Academics/Mathematics/Jones.pdf)
, it is given that an unweighted path graph with $n$ vertices has eigenvalues
$$
2\cos(\pi j/(n+1)),  j = 1,\cdots, n.
$$
All multiplicities are 1. Assuming the edges of the path are weighted in some order, for example, $w_{1,2}\geq w_{2,3}\cdots \geq w_{n-1,n}$ where $w_{j-1,j}$, $j=2,\cdots, n$ is the weight of the edge between vertex $j-1$ and $j$; is there some general expression for the eigenvalues of the weighted path graph?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In general, I would say no. Perhaps with some extra constraints on the weights one could get further. See for example the vast literature on Perron-Frobenius theory and bounds on the dominant eigenvalue.

Comment: Thanks @JacobA. Any thoughts about if there may be any bounds on the spacing between the eigenvalues if the weights are all positive and ordered?